# Como deixar um formulário sempre por trás?

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou tentando deixar um formulário sempre por baixo dos outros formulários, não importa se o usuário clicar nele, ele sempre deve ficar por baixo, mas passível de utilização, algo parecido com o desktop, e aí é que está o problema, não estou a conseguir fazer isso, gostaria de saber qual abordagem devo usar.

Li sobre alguns meios de deixar sempre na frente, não sei se inverter isso, para ficar sempre por baixo daria certo.

Comment: Você está falando de MDI?

Comment: Como,vc ta chamando?

Comment: @Fúlvio, Instanciando e chamando. `Form1 formulario = new Form1();` e `formulario.Show();`.

Comment: @Tiago, sim, MDI.

Comment: Se não for MDI use formulário.ShowDialog();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O seu formulário principal deverá ter a propriedade `IsMdiContaner` setada como `true`.
Os formulários filhos, sendo criados dentro do formulário MDI Container, deverão ser chamados assim:

```c-sharp
ChildForm form = new ChildForm();
form.MdiParent = this;
form.Show();
```

Exemplo de resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: @Fúlvio, sim, mas ele não mencionou o uso de `form.MdiParent = this;`. E já que disse ser MDI que deseja, tem o formulário principal que precisa ser setado como MDI Container também.

Comment: Um formulário filho vai aparecer por cima do pai, o que quero é usar o pai sem jogar o filho para trás dele. Voltando a resposta, onde ficaria esse `IsMdiContaner`? Nas propriedades do formulário?

Comment: @Patrick, ainda continua parecendo MDI para mim. E sobre `IsMdiContainer`, sim, é uma propriedade. Se for usar `ShowDialog` não poderá ser um `MDIChild`.

Comment: @Tiago, fiz o que indicou, duas coisas aconteceram: o formulário ficou com fundo cinza-escuro (como eu poderia retirar essa cor?) e quando chamo o formulário filho, apenas aparecem barras de rolagem em volta do formulário pai.

Comment: @Patrick, o formulário filho você deve estar mandando maximizar automaticamente. Já sobre a cor, realmente não sei. Testei mudar a cor na mão, mas não deu.

Comment: Chequei aqui e ele não está marcado para maximizar automaticamente, o que pode ser?

Comment: @Patrick, pode adicionar seu código e uma imagem de como esta ficando, na sua pergunta?